# Custom webserver caching

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, webserver, embeddedwebserver

I'm working with a custom webserver on an embedded system and having some problems correctly setting my HTTP Headers for caching.

Our webserver is generating all dynamic content as XML and we're using semi-static XSL files to display it with some dynamic JSON requests thrown in for good measure along with semi-static images. I say "semi-static" because the problems occur when we need to do a firmware update which might change the XSL and image files.

Here's what needs to be done: cache the XSL and image files and do not cache the XML and JSON responses. I have full control over the HTTP response and am currently:

1. Using ETags with the XSL and image files, using the modified time and size to generate the ETag
2. Setting Cache-Control: no-cache on the XML and JSON responses

As I said, everything works dandy until a firmware update when the XSL and image files are **sometimes** cached. I've seen it work fine with the latest versions of Firefox and Safari but have had some problems with IE.

I know one solution to this problem would be simply rename the XSL and image files after each version (eg. logo-v1.1.png, logo-v1.2.png) and set the Expires header to a date in the future but this would be difficult with the XSL files and I'd like to avoid this.

Note: There is a clock on the unit but requires the user to set it and might not be 100% reliable which is what might be causing my caching issues when using ETags.

What's the best practice that I should employ? I'd like to avoid as many webserver requests as possible but invalidating old XSL and image files after a software update is the #1 priority.

Answer (score 0):

Are we working on the same project?  I went down a lot of dead ends figuring out the best way to handle this.

I set my .html and my .shtml files (dynamic JSON data) to expire immediately. ("Cache-Control: no-cache\r\nExpires: -1\r\n")
Everything else is set to expire in 10 years. ("Cache-Control: max-age=290304000\r\n")

My makefile runs a perl script over all the .html files and identifies what you call "semi-static" content (images, javascript, css.)  The script then runs a md5 checksum on those files and appends the checksum to the file:

```
<script type="text/Javascript" src="js/all.js?7f26be24ed2d05e7d0b844351e3a49b1">
```

Everything after the question mark is ignored, but no browser will cache it unless everything between the quotes matches.

I use all.js and all.css because everything's combined and minified using the same script.

Out of curiosity, what embedded webserver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Cache-Control: no-store`. `no-cache` tells the client that the response **can** be cached; it just generally isn't reused unless the cache can't contact the origin server.

BTW, setting an ETag alone won't make the response cacheable; you should also set `Cache-Control: max-age=nnn`.

You can check how your responses will be treated with http://redbot.org/